# Node.js app with a MySQL database deployed on heroku keeps crashing

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku, heroku-cli

I am new to Node.js and I have an application that I have deployed to Heroku with a MySQL database.

However,I keep getting an error.
The app works only for a time after I deploy on Heroku. It suddenly stops working and I get the following error:

```
   events.js:160
               throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

   Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
   at Protocol.end (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:113:13)
   at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:109:28)
   at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
   at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7)
   at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
   at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
   State changed from up to crashed
   Process exited with status 1
```

Here is my code:

```
  var express = require('express');
  var app = express();
  var mysql = require('mysql')
  var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  const sortBy = require('sort-array')


  app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
  app.set("view engine", "ejs");
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));



  var db_config = {
  host: 'us-cdbr-iron-east-05.cleardb.net',
  user: 'REDACTED',
  password: 'REDACTED',
  database: 'heroku_REDACTED'
  };

 var connection;
 connection = mysql.createConnection(db_config); 

 var count2 = 10;
 var count3 = 20;
 var count4 = 10;
 //SELECT COUNT(*) AS count2 FROM photos

 app.get("/", function(req, res){
 var q_users = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count1 FROM users";

 connection.query(q_users, function(err,results, fields){
 if(err) throw err;
 var count1 = results[0].count1;
 //res.send(results);
 res.render("home", {data1: count1, data2: count2, data3: count3, 
  data4: count4});
   });
  });



  app.post('/adduser', function(req,res){
  var person = { username: req.body.username};

   connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', person, function(err, 
   result){
    if(err) throw err;
    res.redirect("/");

    });
    });




    app.post('/deleteuserid', function(req,res){
     var id = req.body.userid;

     connection.query('DELETE FROM users WHERE id = ?', id, function(err, result){
      if(err) throw err;
      //res.send(result);
      res.redirect("/countpictures");

      });
    });


  app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
  });
```

Can someone please tell me how to fix this?  I have a lot of SQL queries and I think some form of timeout is occuring. Please tell me what changes should I make to avoid this error, so that my app is stable and doesnt crash after every 5 minutes of deployment.

Comment: No security credentials, please. Change that password **now.**

Comment: sry..will take care in the future! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, MySQL will eventually close the connection after it's been idle for too long...

To avoid this, you need to use a connection pool. Connection pools manage connections for you, reconnecting when necessary. For more details on connection pooling, see https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections.

Hence, you can make your code more robust by replacing the connection with the following:

```
const connection = mysql.createPool({ connectionLimit: 5, ...db_config });
```

Ideally, you'd also rename the *connection* variable to *pool* as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and I solved it like this

```
var mysql = require ('mysql');
var pool = mysql.createPool ({
  host: 'xxxx',
  user: 'xxxx',
  password: 'xxxx',
  database: 'xxxx'
});
module.exports = pool;
```

Comment: where to put the code ? in server.js ?  because my config js has the pool ```production: {
    username: process.env.PROD_DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.PROD_DB_PASSWORD,
.....
    pool: {
      max: 5,
      min: 0,
      acquire: 50000,
      idle: 20000
    }
  }```